# To find a function of real numbers using two given relations.

Tags: real-numbers, functional-equations

Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that the following equation hold for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

(i) $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$
(ii) $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$

Show that for $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x$.

I know to solve this if it is instead of real numbers, it is integers using mathematical induction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $f(1)\neq0$. Then, $f(a)=f(a\cdot 1)=f(a)f(1)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, which means $f(1)=1$. That also implies that for all $z\in\mathbb Z$, $f(z)=z$. By property (ii), that also implies $f(q)=q\forall q\in\mathbb Q$. Now, for all $x>0$, $\exists y<x$ such that $x=y\cdot y$. So, $f(x)=f(y)^2$. This implies that the function must be continuous on $\mathbb R^+$, which implies $f(x\geq0)=x$ (since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. Then, $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. If $f(1)=0$, then obviously, we can conduct the same logic as we've done here to show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)^2$$and that therefore $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$.

If $f(1)=0$, then, for any $x$, $f(x)=f(x\times1)=f(x)\times f(1)=0$.

Now, suppose that $f(1)=1$. Note that $f$ is order-preserving. In fact, if $x\geqslant0$, then $x=y^2$ for some $y$ and so$$f(x)=f(y^2)=f(y)^2\geqslant0.$$Therefore, $a\leqslant b\implies f(a)\leqslant f(b)$.

On the other hand, $f|_{\mathbb Q}$  is linear. In fact, since $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, it is easy to prove by inductain that if $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and if $q\in\mathbb Q$, $f(nq)=nf(q)$. But then, if $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $n<0$, then $f\bigl((-n)q\bigr)=(-n)f(q)$, which is equivalent to $f(nq)=nf(q)$. Finally, if $n\in\mathbb Z$ and $m\in\mathbb N$, then$$mf\left(\frac nmq\right)=f(nq)=nf(q)$$and therefore $f\left(\frac nmq\right)=\frac nmf(q)$.

It follows from this fact together with the fact that $f(1)=1$ that $(\forall q\in\mathbb Q):f(q)=q$. But this, together with the fact that $f$ is order preserving (and that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$) implies that $f$ is the identity function. In fact, if $x\in\mathbb R$ and if $\varepsilon>0$, you take rational numbers $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that $q_1\leqslant x\leqslant q_2$ and that $q_2-q_1<\varepsilon$. But then $f(q_1)\leqslant f(x)\leqslant f(q_2)$, which means that $q_1\leqslant f(x)\leqslant q_2$. So, $\left\lvert f(x)-x\right\rvert<\varepsilon$. Since this occurs for each $\varepsilon>0$, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Some doubts.. f/Q is linear. how?   next.. "f(q)=q. But this, together with the fact that f is order preserving (and that Q is dense in R) implies that f is the identity function" .. Can you elaborate on this.. like which theorem

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.