# Properties of a function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of all real numbers and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that the following hold true $\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R} $:

$\ f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

$\ f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$

Show that for all x belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ either $\ f(x)=0$ or $\ f(x)=x$.

I know that there is an answer to this question under the following link:

[To find a function of real numbers using two given relations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162119/to-find-a-function-of-real-numbers-using-two-given-relations)

However, I want to know if I can use field automorphism to deduce the required result.

I have proceeded by showing that since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field therefore $\ ker f$ , being an ideal is equal to$\ (0)$ or $\mathbb{R}$. If $\ ker f = \mathbb{R} $ then $\ f(x)=0$ $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $.

Otherwise $\ f(x)$ is injective. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Is $f$ a field homomorphism?

Comment: No there is no such fact mentioned. But I felt that the definition of $\ f$ was pointing towards a homomorphism.Please correct me if I am wrong in my assumption

Comment: What you have stated above in your question implies that you are looking for a field homomorphism. If $f$ is a field homomorphism then it’s either an injective map or $f(x):=0$.

Comment: I am actually stuck at the point where I have proved that f is injective. How do I proceed further?

Comment: You can show that either $f(1) = 0$ [which makes the map the zero map] or $f(1) = 1$ from $f(1) = f(1*1) = f(1)f(1)$ (using the fact that the image lives in the integral domain $\mathbb R$. I am pretty sure it is not possible to show $f(x) = x$ without further input like that in the question you link. This is because in general fields can have nontrivial automorphisms and so the claim needs to incorporate some extra information about $\mathbb R$ that distinguishes it from other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose that $f(1)$ is not $0$ then you have $f(1)$=$f(1)f(1)$(second condition) so $f(1)=1$.Now: $f(0)$=$f(0)+f(0)$ (first condition) so $f(0)=0$ and for every $x\in \mathbb R$ you have $0=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x)+f(-x)$ so $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ (1).Also, for n$\in \mathbb N$ $1=f(1)=f(n/n)=nf(1/n)$->$f(1/n)=1/n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.Same logic give us that $f(m/n)=mf(1/n)=m/n$ for m,n $\in$ $\mathbb N$.From (1) we have that f(m/n)=m/n for every m$\in$ $\mathbb Z$,n$\in$ $\mathbb N$ so you have f(q)=q for q $\in$ $\mathbb Q$.Now its a good exercise to prove that if you have a CONTINUOUS(this is a must) function and f(x)=g(x) for every x$\in$ $\mathbb Q$ then f(x)=g(x) for every x$\in$ $\mathbb R$. I am pretty sure that you need that f is **CONTINUOUS** function(its same logic to prove that with $f(1)=0$ then $f=0$)